# Load CHAT Messages not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ajax

This my code for send realtime message.

After send message, it is not display unless i refresh the page.

I want this chat box message to show the new message entered. 
This is to show the user List In the left side of the page:

```
$(".user-w").click(function() {
var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
// alert(user_id);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Message/getMessageByLists/')?>",
    data: {
        'user_id': user_id
    },
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#loadMessages").html(data);
    }
}); });
```

This is Send function:

```
$("#sendMessage").click(function(e) 
{e.preventDefault();// alert("test");
  var msg = $("#message_text").val();
  var touser = $("#touser").val();
 //var reservation_id = $("#reservation_id").val();
  if (!msg || msg.length == 0) {
     alert("enter a message");
    } else {
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Message/addMessage')?>",
    //  data:{'msg' : msg, 'touser' : touser, 'reservation_id' : reservation_id},
    data: {
        'msg': msg,
        'touser': touser
    },
    datatype: 'text',
    //  Page.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
            //$("#loadMessages").load();
            $("#message_text").val("");
        } else {
            alert("noo eroor chat message");
        }
    },
});
//return false;
}  }); // End Send Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: thanks is good , sorry , e is not my basic Lang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am not wrong then, their might be an element with class as "user-w", also that element have "id" attribute too. So you can just execute following line, after sending the message to user.

```
$(".user-w[id='"+ touser +"']").trigger("click");
```

above line needs to placed in "success" method, like as below:

```
if (data == 1) {
    //$("#loadMessages").load();
    $("#message_text").val("");
    $(".user-w[id='"+ touser +"']").trigger("click");
} else {
    alert("noo eroor chat message");
}
```

Comment: work - i am happy , i love u , one more Q , how i can make the first chat show when open the chat page was the latest page

Comment: ok, please check whether you are getting element with below line, where touser can be any value that you have at your end:
$(".user-w[id='"+ touser +"']").length; then after just try to perform $(".user-w[id='"+ touser +"']").trigger("click");

Comment: for making first chat show when open the chat page. You can try following line: $(".user-w:first").trigger("click");  This will select first user from show list of users & display it's related chats opened up.

Comment: where i put this line ?

Comment: you can put it in document.ready function, so it will gets executed as page gets loaded.

Comment: ok, put it in document.ready function but after $(".user-w").click(function() {}); click event binding.

Comment: Generally it should work, because you are doing: $(".user-w:first").trigger("click"); means getting first element from list of elements with a class ".user-w" and calling a click function of it. Where this click event needs to defined before calling line: $(".user-w:first").trigger("click");

Comment: it work , befor was not work couse the alert , thanks vey much , if i face any other issue in chat , can i call u here again ?

Comment: i have one more Q , if u availbe ?

Comment: can u check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424540/get-the-receiver-id-in-sending-chat